# How to assign a data attribute of a subclass to attributes of its parent class

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have a class Rectangle with data attributes width and height, I want a subclass Square with data attribute side_length.

How do I make it so that square.width and square.height give its side length? i.e same as square.side

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, side)
        self.side = side
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: What do you mean by this statement ? __"square.width and square.height give its side length"__

Comment: For an instance of the class Square (that I've also called square), when I use square.width or square.height to return the data attributes width and height, which are attributes of the parent class Rectangle, I would like these to return the same value as square.side (where square is an attribute of the class Square) since a squares side lengths are the same for width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the constructor for Rectangle.

`super(Square,self).__init__(side, side)`

or you could have properties to return those attributes.  I'd edge towards the super.

```
@property
def length(self):
   return self.side

@property
def width(self):
   return self.side
```

Things get more complicated if you can change the `side`, `height` or `width` attribute after creating the object.  You need to keep `width` and `height` synched and coherent.  One possible way is to do away entirely with `side` as a stored attribute on Square and instead have it as a read-write property that updates Rectangle's width and height.

#### to keep height/width/side sorted after the initial constructors:

```
class Rectangle:

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self._height = value

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        self._width = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return(f"{self.__class__.__name__}:{self.height=} {self.width=}")

    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

class Square(Rectangle):

    def __repr__(self):
        return(f"{self.__class__.__name__}:{self.side=}")

    @property
    def side(self):
        return self._width

    @side.setter
    def side(self, value):
        self._width = value
        self._height = value

    def __init__(self, side):
        super(Square, self).__init__(side, side)

    #these are here so you can't cheat and vary height and width
    #independently on a square
    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.side

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        self.side = value

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._side

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self.side = value



rectangle = Rectangle(5,2)
print(rectangle)
rectangle.height = 6
print(rectangle)

square = Square(3)
print(square)
square.side = 6
print(square)
square.height = 9
print(square)
```

#### output:

```
$ py test_square.py
Rectangle:self.height=5 self.width=2
Rectangle:self.height=6 self.width=2
Square:self.side=3
Square:self.side=6
Square:self.side=9
```

Comment: I would like to be able to change the side length attribute after creation since I have methods defined on the rectangle class to change width and height. Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: @ogprog: If being able to reconfigure the side lengths independently from each other after construction is a feature of your Rectangle class, then your Square breaks Liskov substitution - you cannot do things with a Square that you can with a Rectangle. In that case, your Square class should not be a Rectangle subclass, or you should remove the side length reconfiguration feature from Rectangle.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  not necessarily.  If you consider that altering width or height of a Square is the same as altering the side *and you write properties accordingly* then you don't break LSP.  this is what I did here.  Is the overall idea good OOP?  Mmmmm, not at all sure but at least a square remains a square *in this particular constrained scenario* and I had fun with setters which I rarely use.

Comment: @JLPeyret that's great thank you! I think that is as as we can get to the specification of the programme I'm trying to build, whilst still keeping the height setter methods on the Square